# findBy query not returning correct page info

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a Person collection that is made up of the following structure

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ddd6795218e7964fa9086c"),
    "_class" : "uk.gov.gsi.hmpo.belt.domain.person.Person",
    "imagesMatch" : true,
    "matchResult" : {
        "_id" : null,
        "score" : 1234,
        "matchStatus" : "matched",
        "confirmedMatchStatus" : "notChecked"
    },
    "earlierImage" : DBRef("image", ObjectId("54ddd6795218e7964fa9086b")),
    "laterImage" : DBRef("image", ObjectId("54ddd67a5218e7964fa908a9")),
    "tag" : DBRef("tag", ObjectId("54ddd6795218e7964fa90842"))
}`

Notice that the "tag" is a DBRef.

I've got a Spring Data finder that looks like the following:

```
Page<Person> findByMatchResultNotNullAndTagId(@Param("tagId") String tagId, Pageable page);
```

When this code is executed the find query looks like the following:

```
{ matchResult: { $ne: null }, tag: { $ref: "tag", $id: ObjectId('54ddd6795218e7964fa90842') } } sort: {} projection: {} skip: 0 limit: 1
```

Which is fine, I get a collection of 1 person back (limit=1).  However the page details are not correct.  I have 31 persons in the collection so I should have 31 pages.  What I get is the following:

```
"page" : {
  "size" : 1,
  "totalElements" : 0,
  "totalPages" : 0,
  "number" : 0
 }
```

The count query looks like the following:

```
{ count: "person", query: { matchResult: { $ne: null }, tag.id: "54ddd6795218e7964fa90842" } }
```

That tag.id doesn't look correct to me compared with the equivalent find query above.

I've found that if I add a new method to org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations:

```
public interface MongoOperations {
```

```
    public long count(Query query, Class<?> entityClass, String collectionName);
}
```

And then re-jig `AbstractMongoQuery.execute(Query query)` to use that method instead of the similar method without the entityClass parameter then I get the correct paging results.

Question:  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Spring Data Mongo?

**Edit**

Taking inspiration from Christoph I've added the following test code on Git https://github.com/tedp/Spring-Data-Test

Answer (score 0):

The information contained in the `Page` returned depends on the query executed. Assuming a total number of 31 elements in you collection, only a few of them, or even just one might match the given criteria by referencing the tag with `id: 54ddd6795218e7964fa90842`. Therefore you only get the total elements that match the query, and not the total elements within your collection.

Comment: Hi Christoph, I know the query returns all 31 records but it is limited to return just one record.  However I would expect the `Page` to tell me there are 31 pages.

Comment: that's strange - which version of sd-mongodb are you using. tried to reproduce and everythings seems to work fine for the testcase I wrote...

Comment: I added the testcase there >  https://gist.github.com/christophstrobl/9a73062c153300757a4e

Comment: That test case fails in my setup.  I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.1 RELEASE which depends on Spring Data 1.6.1 RELEASE.  I'll provide a complete project on git for you (or anyone else) to look at.  Thanks so much for your interest!

Comment: I've added the following test case which demonstrates the problem https://github.com/tedp/Spring-Data-Test

Comment: I see - yes that's an issue (see [DATAMONGO-1120](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1120)) with version 1.6.1 that has already been fixed in 1.6.2. Nevertheless I cheked the testcase against those versions and as expected it failed in 1.6.1 and worked fine with 1.6.2.

Comment: Correct, I only checked that I was using the latest version of Spring Boot and not the latest Spring Data.  Sorry about that and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This bug was actually fixed  [DATAMONGO-1120](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1120) as pointed out by Christoph.  I needed to override the spring data version to use 1.6.2.RELEASE until the next iteration of Spring Boot where presumably Spring Data will be up lifted to at least 1.6.2.RELEASE.